# How to check whether two elements in an xml has same value for its attribute

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Consider the following example,

I need to check whether any two country has same neighbor , by comparing `name` attribute of all the neighbour tags.
I am using `.attrib` and then comparing the dictionary which is the output of .attrib based on key as of now. Is there a simpler way to check exactly the attribute ?

```
 <data>
        <country name="Liechtenstein">
            <rank>1</rank>
            <year>2008</year>
            <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
            <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
            <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
        </country>
        <country name="Singapore">
            <rank>4</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
            <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
            <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
        </country>
        <country name="Panama">
            <rank>68</rank>
            <year>2011</year>
            <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
            <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
            <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
        </country>
</data>
```

I am using lxml in python.

Answer (score 1):

```
for every country as c
    for every neighbor of c as n
        neighbors[n].push(c)


for every neighbor in neighbors
     if count(neighbors[neighbor]) > 1
          ding ding ding
```